# Confusion in loops when repeated insertion from array in PDO when get data from input[]

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

- have a special project for attendance and absence as a duty for the university
- i created a form that git his input form data base  by use []  to git array
- every things work fine but :
- ** when I insert data from my form just I can't find right way to make it work fine **
- I used to loop ** for ** for go to the next index and ** foreach ** to get the index of the radio button

this is my table i have it form database:

[image: table get input data form database]

```html
<br>
<div class="row  justify-content-md-center">
    <h2>شاشة ادخال الحضور والغياب للطالب </h2>
    <br><br>
</div>
<br><br>

<form action="" dir="rtl" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>اختيار بيانات التحظير :</legend>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <select class="form-control" name="phase_student">
                    <option value="">المرحلة</option>
                    <?php
                    $QueryDB = "SELECT * FROM `phase_student`";
                    $DoQuery = mysqli_query($Con, $QueryDB);
                    $ChekRows = mysqli_num_rows($DoQuery);


                    if ($ChekRows > 0) {
                        while ($Rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DoQuery)) {
                            echo "<option value='" . $Rows['num_phase'] . "'> " . $Rows['phase'] . " </option>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "<option value=''>لا توجد بيانات مرحلة   </option>";
                    } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col">

                <select class="form-control" name="classe">
                    <option value="">الصف</option>
                    <?php

                    $QueryDB2 = "SELECT * FROM `classe`";
                    $DoQuery2 = mysqli_query($Con, $QueryDB2);
                    $ChekRows2 = mysqli_num_rows($DoQuery2);

                    if ($ChekRows2 > 0) {
                        while ($Rows2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DoQuery2)) {
                            echo "<option value='" . $Rows2['num_class'] . "'> " . $Rows2['class'] . " </option>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "<option value=''>لا توجد بيان  الصفوف  </option>";
                    } ?>

                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col">

                <select class=" form-control" name="prong">
                    <option value="">الشعبة</option>
                    <?php

                    $QueryDB3 = "SELECT * FROM `prong`";
                    $DoQuery3 = mysqli_query($Con, $QueryDB3);
                    $ChekRows3 = mysqli_num_rows($DoQuery3);

                    if ($ChekRows3 > 0) {
                        while ($Rows3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DoQuery3)) {
                            echo "<option value='" . $Rows3['num_prong'] . "'> " . $Rows3['prong'] . " </option>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "<option value=''>لا توجد بيان  شعب   </option>";
                    } ?>
                </select>
            </div>

        </div>

        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <select class="form-control" name="item">
                    <option value="">اسم المادة</option>
                    <?php


                    $QueryDB6 = "SELECT * FROM `item`";
                    $DoQuery6 = mysqli_query($Con, $QueryDB6);
                    $ChekRows6 = mysqli_num_rows($DoQuery6);

                    if ($ChekRows6 > 0) {
                        while ($Rows6 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DoQuery6)) {
                            echo "<option value='" . $Rows6['num_item'] . "'> " . $Rows6['item'] . " </option>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "<option value=''>لا توجد بيان المواد    </option>";
                    } ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col">

                <select class=" form-control" name="monthe">
                    <option value="">الشهر</option>
                    <?php

                    $QueryDB5 = "SELECT * FROM `monthe`";
                    $DoQuery5 = mysqli_query($Con, $QueryDB5);
                    $ChekRows5 = mysqli_num_rows($DoQuery5);

                    if ($ChekRows5 > 0) {
                        while ($Rows5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DoQuery5)) {
                            echo "<option value='" . $Rows5['num_month'] . "'> " . $Rows5['monthe'] . " </option>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "<option value=''>لا توجد بيان  الاشهر   </option>";
                    } ?>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col">

                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="thisDay" value="">
            </div>

        </div>
    </fieldset>


    <br>
    <br>


    <div class="container">

        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>متسلسل</th>
                <th>اسم الطالب</th>
                <th>حاضر</th>
                <th>غائب</th>
                <th>مستئذن</th>
                <th> ملاحظات</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <?php

                $queryStu = "SELECT * FROM `student_academia` ";
                $DoQuerystu = mysqli_query($Con, $queryStu);
                $ChekRowsstu = mysqli_num_rows($DoQuerystu);

                if ($ChekRowsstu > 0) {
                    while ($Rowsstu = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DoQuerystu)) {
                        echo " <td> <span> " . $Rowsstu['num__student'] . "</span> <input type='hidden' name ='IdStu[]' value='" . $Rowsstu['num__student'] . "' > </td>";
                        echo " <td> <span> " . $Rowsstu['name_student'] . "</span> <input type='hidden' name ='NaStu[]' value='" . $Rowsstu['name_student'] . "' > </td>";
                        echo "  <td>
                    <div class=\"form-check\">
                        <label class=\"form-check-label\">
                            <input class=\"form-check-input\" type=\"radio\" name=\"attend[" . $Rowsstu['num__student'] . "]\" value=\"1\" id=" . $Rowsstu['num__student'] . ">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class=\"form-check\">
                        <label class=\"form-check-label\">
                            <input class=\"form-check-input\" type=\"radio\" name=\"attend[" . $Rowsstu['num__student'] . "]\" value=\"0\"  id=" . $Rowsstu['num__student'] . ">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class=\"form-check\">
                        <label class=\"form-check-label\">
                            <input class=\"form-check-input\" type=\"radio\" name=\"excusable[" . $Rowsstu['num__student'] . "]\" value=\"1\"  id=" . $Rowsstu['num__student'] . ">
                            <input class=\"form-check-input sr-only\" type=\"radio\" name=\"excusable[" . $Rowsstu['num__student'] . "]\" value=\"0\"  id=" . $Rowsstu['num__student'] . " checked >
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </td> 
                  <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='attendNote[]' placeholder='ملاحظات ' /></td>
            </tr>
                ";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "لا توجد بيان  طلاب";
                }

                ?>


            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>

    <br>
    <br>

    <div class=" row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-3">
            <input class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="savedata"
                   value="حفظ"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <input class="btn  btn-block  btn-outline-warning  " type="reset" value="مسح"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn  btn-block btn-outline-danger" name="close">خروج
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

this is whine I post my form :

```html
<?php
include "header.php";
//connect to data base oraginal con
include "ConDB.php";
// connect to database but Php Data Opject conect
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=school_db", "root", "");
// utf8 supurt arabic
$db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
// show error on connect
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// when some body click save button
if (isset($_POST['savedata'])) {

    $phase_student = $_POST['phase_student'];
    $classe = $_POST['classe'];
    $prong = $_POST['prong'];
    $item = $_POST['item'];
    $monthe = $_POST['monthe'];
    $thisDay = $_POST['thisDay'];
//array
    $IdStu = $_POST['IdStu'];
    $NaStu = $_POST['NaStu'];
    $attends = $_POST['attend'];
    $excusables = $_POST['excusable'];
    $attendNote = $_POST['attendNote'];


    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($NaStu);

    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($IdStu);
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($attends);
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($attendNote);
    echo "<br>";
    var_dump($excusables);

    echo "<br>";
    /*
               $queryInsertAttend = "INSERT INTO `outcom_month`(`num__student`, `name_student`, `num_month`, `num_class`,`class`, `prong`, `num_item`, `item`, `duties(20)`, `oral(20)`, `assiduity(20)`, `edit(40)`, `total`, `tribnte`, `note_avant`, `note_guardian`) VALUES (
       $num__student ,$num__student, $num_month ,$num_class,$num_class,$prong,$num_item,$num_item,
       $duties,$oral,$assiduity,$edit,$edit,$tribnte,$note_avant,$note_avant)";

       **/
//
//        $id = new ArrayIterator($IdStu);
//        $at = new ArrayIterator($attend);
//        $atnot = new ArrayIterator($attendNote);
//
//        $dataa = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ALL);
//
//        $dataa->attachIterator($id);
//        $dataa->attachIterator($at);
//        $dataa->attachIterator($atnot);
////
    if (!empty($_POST)) {

        //$insert_stu_Attend = $db->prepare("insert into test  values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $insert_stu_Attend = $db->prepare("insert into test2  values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $insert_stu_Attend->bindParam(1, $first);
        $insert_stu_Attend->bindParam(2, $second);
        $insert_stu_Attend->bindParam(3, $third);
        $insert_stu_Attend->bindParam(4, $forth);
        $insert_stu_Attend->bindParam(5, $fifth);
        $insert_stu_Attend->bindParam(6, $sixth);
        $insert_stu_Attend->bindParam(7, $seventh);
        $insert_stu_Attend->bindParam(8, $eighth);

        for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
            foreach ($IdStu as $s) {
                $dd = 1;
                $first = $IdStu[$i];
                $second = $monthe;
                $third = $item;
                $forth = $classe;
                $fifth = $thisDay;
                $sixth = $attends[$s];
                $seventh = $excusables[$s];
                $eighth = $attendNote[$i];
                $insert_stu_Attend->execute();
            }
        }
    }


} else {
    echo '<br>';
    echo " لم يتم الادخال";
}

?>
```

every time i get the only fist row in table.

**Tabke definition:**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    num__student int(11) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    year_study date NOT NULL,
    num_item int(11) NOT NULL,
    calss varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    date_day date NOT NULL,
    attendee tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    excusable tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    nate mediumtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: change to `bindValue` it works much better with less confusion, especially in such loops

Comment: since you do `foreach ($IdStu as $s) {` why do you `$IdStu[$i]);` instead of just `$s[$i]);` I guess

Comment: @Alex hi  i change it to bindValue

Comment: @Alex  is the same I think but   some time I'm not focus   '$s[$i] ' but I change it thanks

Comment: I found an answer, I deleted my comment that didn't solve anything, just a moment.

Comment: @RafaelBoszko   I really appreciate your cooperation

Comment: @sean-bright thanks for edit my question

Comment: Give us the `CREATE TABLE` syntax, e.g. the table definition, please.

Comment: I see no `form` tag! Please provide the whole code. And write the name  of the files in which the codes reside.

Comment: @dakis  this is the code for table ** `CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `num__student` int(11) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `year_study` date NOT NULL,
  `num_item` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `calss` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `date_day` date NOT NULL,
  `attendee` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `excusable` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `nate` mediumtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`**

Comment: @dakis this is my form tag <form action="" dir="rtl" method="POST"> and the cod of php is in same page

Comment: Again: please give us the whole codes! I mean, reedit your question and put them there. You need to understand that we must test your codes too.

Comment: @dakis i  cant past all code hire it's see to long characters

Comment: @Anas, var_dump the $IdStu variable and add it to the main question, please

Comment: Ok. Put the `form` tag at the right position in the question's code.

Comment: Why do you have two tables? `select * from student_academia` and `insert into test...`? Give us the definition for the table `student_academia` too.

Comment: @dakis I edit question ...  I take data from `student_academia` and is work fine their is no problem in it

Comment: Anas, unfortunately the php code is incomplete. I can not test and solve until you post a complete code. From where do all those variables come (`$IdStu`, `$monthe`, etc)?

Comment: @dakis its come form select input[] and when I do  `var_dump` is give my an array   I well add all my php code to the question

Comment: Ok. I am waiting for it.

Comment: @dakis I add all  `php code ` to the question .     now the problem is when I post is insert 4 row for 2 student , is make it duplicate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177761/discussion-between-dakis-and-anas).

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you are using the `bindParam` in not the most correct way.

According to this: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp, you should bind them before the loop and use the loop to only adapt the variables you binded.

I'm gonna use your code as example, ok?

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $insert_stu_Attend = $db->prepare("insert into test  values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $insert_stu_Attend->bindParam(1, $first);
    $insert_stu_Attend->bindParam(2, $second);
    $insert_stu_Attend->bindParam(3, $third);
    $insert_stu_Attend->bindParam(4, $forth);
    $insert_stu_Attend->bindParam(5, $fifth);
    $insert_stu_Attend->bindParam(6, $sixth);
    $insert_stu_Attend->bindParam(7, $seventh);
    $insert_stu_Attend->bindParam(8, $eighth);

    foreach ($IdStu as $key => $s) {
        $dd = 1;
        $first = $IdStu[$key];
        $second = $monthe;
        $third = $item;
        $forth = $classe;
        $fifth = $thisDay;
        $sixth = $attends[$s];
        $seventh = $excusables[$s];
        $eighth = $attendNote[$key];
        $insert_stu_Attend->execute();
    }
}
```

According to the documentation, it should work. Let me know how it went.

**EDIT**
I removed the for and kept only the foreach, because I assume you are using the FOR to loop through results from different arrays considering the number of users sent for this result.

Comment: I get error **Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '150' for key 'num__student_2'**

Comment: Well that's a great sign then. It means it's trying to insert twice. :D Please var_dump the $IdStu variable and add it to the main question.

Comment: yes  it's insert the first row and thin give the error  :)

Comment: when  I remove unique is insert all table but twice  .. is there somethings I can do

Comment: yes, var_dump the $IdStu so we can understand how the data looks like, and add it to the main question, please.

Comment: `array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "150" [1]=> string(3) "199" }`  this is the    `var_dump`     for     `$IdStu`

Comment: Ok Anas, lets talk in a chat, there is a lot happening.
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177760/anas-loop

Answer (score 1):

I decided to write an answer, which should serve you as a guidance, even though there are a lot of unknowns for us. How you decide to fetch the data from `student_academia` and to save it to the `test` table is up to you.

**To do**

- There is commented line labeled `@todo`. Search for it and uncomment it to see how the structure of the posted values looks like, e.g. the values in the `$_POST` variable.
- Replace my db credentials with yours, before testing my code.

**Some suggestions**

- Use only the PDO extension. Though I still used both mysqli (object-oriented) and PDO in my codes.
- Separate the codes regarding fetching from the database from the ones used to display the fetched values. E.g. fetch and save all data (that you need to use in your form) into arrays, first. Then, in the form codes, just iterate through these arrays and read their data. This is a desirable design principle and it's called [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).
- Don't print HTML codes from PHP. So don't write lines like `echo "<option value='3'>Item 3</option>";`.

In principle, your codes should be in such a clear way written, that they are really easy and quick to understand by any other person. Here some directions, based on how I code and what naming conventions I use:

- Use the plural for the table names, like: `items`, `students`.
- In a table, try to always use an autoincremental PK (e.g. primary key) column, with the singular of the table name, like: in table `items` the column `item_id`, in table `students` the column `student_id`. If, for example, you want to have a column with a UNIQUE index, then it would be another column beside the PK column. For example, in `students` table you would have these two columns: `student_id` and `identifier`. Note that I used `identifier` instead of `num__student`.
- In db tables use clear names. So, in a db table use `year_of_study` instead of `year_study`. Or instead of `num_item` use `item_id`, or `item_identifier`.
- In php, use intention-revealing name. For example, instead of `$ChekRows = mysqli_num_rows(...);` use `$numberOfRows = mysqli_num_rows(...);`. Or, instead of `$IdStu` and `$NaStu`, use `$studentIdentifier` and `$studentName`. Or, as function name, instead of `getStudents($id)` use `getStudentsById($id)`.

And here are some good resources:

- [Clean, high quality code](https://www.butterfly.com.au/blog/website-development/clean-high-quality-code-a-guide-on-how-to-become-a-better-programmer)
- PSR 1, PSR 2, PSR 4 from [PHP Standards Recommendations](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/)
- [Treating PHP Delusions](https://phpdelusions.net/)
- [Clean Code III: Functions - Robert C. Martin](https://vimeo.com/12643301) and [a written short version](https://herbertograca.com/2016/09/03/clean-code-3-functions-by-robert-c-martin-uncle-bob/)

Good luck.

---

**index.php**

```
<?php
require 'header.php';
require 'connection_mysqli.php';
require 'connection_pdo.php';

/*
 * Signalize if the posted data was sucessfully saved in the "test" table,
 * so that a message is displayed after the save operation is finished.
 */
$dataSaved = FALSE;

// Operations upon form submission.
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    /*
     * @todo Uncomment this line to see how the structure of the posted values looks like.
     */
    // echo '<pre>' . print_r($_POST, TRUE) . '</pre>';

    // Get the values from the options list.
    $phaseStudent = empty($_POST['phaseStudent']) ? NULL : $_POST['phaseStudent'];
    $class = empty($_POST['class']) ? NULL : $_POST['class'];
    $prong = empty($_POST['prong']) ? NULL : $_POST['prong'];
    $item = empty($_POST['item']) ? NULL : $_POST['item'];
    $monthe = empty($_POST['monthe']) ? NULL : $_POST['monthe'];
    $thisDay = empty($_POST['thisDay']) ? NULL : $_POST['thisDay'];

    // Get the values from the students list.
    $studentIds = $_POST['studentId'] ?? [];
    $studentNames = $_POST['studentName'] ?? [];
    $attends = $_POST['attend'] ?? [];
    $excusables = $_POST['excusable'] ?? [];
    $attendNotes = $_POST['attendNote'] ?? [];

    // Save the values for each student.
    if ($studentIds) {
        foreach ($studentIds as $key => $studentId) {
            /*
             * Check if a record with the posted student
             * id already exists in the "test" table.
             */
            $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*)
                        FROM test
                        WHERE num__student = :num__student';

            $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

            $statement->execute([
                ':num__student' => $studentId,
            ]);

            $numberOfFoundRecords = $statement->fetchColumn(0);

            /*
             * If a record with the posted student id already exists in the
             * "test" table, then update it. Otherwise insert a new record.
             */
            if ($numberOfFoundRecords > 0) { // Record exists already. So update.
                $sql = 'UPDATE test
                        SET
                            year_study = :year_study,
                            num_item = :num_item,
                            class = :class,
                            date_day = :date_day,
                            attendee = :attendee,
                            excusable = :excusable,
                            note = :note
                        WHERE num__student = :num__student';

                $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

                $statement->execute([
                    ':year_study' => $monthe,
                    ':num_item' => $item,
                    ':class' => $class,
                    ':date_day' => $thisDay,
                    ':attendee' => array_key_exists($studentId, $attends) ? $attends[$studentId] : 0,
                    ':excusable' => array_key_exists($studentId, $excusables) ? 1 : 0,
                    ':note' => empty($attendNotes[$studentId]) ? NULL : $attendNotes[$studentId],
                    ':num__student' => $studentId,
                ]);
            } else {// Record does not exist. So insert.
                $sql = 'INSERT INTO test (
                            num__student,
                            year_study,
                            num_item,
                            class,
                            date_day,
                            attendee,
                            excusable,
                            note
                        ) VALUES (
                            :num__student,
                            :year_study,
                            :num_item,
                            :class,
                            :date_day,
                            :attendee,
                            :excusable,
                            :note
                        )';

                $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

                $statement->execute([
                    ':num__student' => $studentId,
                    ':year_study' => $monthe,
                    ':num_item' => $item,
                    ':class' => $class,
                    ':date_day' => $thisDay,
                    ':attendee' => array_key_exists($studentId, $attends) ? $attends[$studentId] : 0,
                    ':excusable' => array_key_exists($studentId, $excusables) ? 1 : 0,
                    ':note' => empty($attendNotes[$studentId]) ? NULL : $attendNotes[$studentId],
                ]);
            }
        }

        $dataSaved = TRUE;
    }
}

// Fetch the phase students.
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM phase_student';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$phaseStudents = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$result->close();

// Fetch the classes.
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM classe';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$classes = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$result->close();

// Fetch the prongs.
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM prong';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$prongs = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$result->close();

// Fetch the items.
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM item';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$items = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$result->close();

// Fetch the months.
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM monthe';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$monthes = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$result->close();

// Fetch the student academias.
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM student_academia ORDER BY name_student ASC';
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$students = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$result->close();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <!-- CSS assets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- JS assets -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                padding: 20px;
            }

            .page-title {
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }

            .options-list {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }

            .students-list {
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
            <h2 class="page-title">شاشة ادخال الحضور والغياب للطالب </h2>
        </div>

        <form action="" dir="rtl" method="POST">
            <?php
            if ($dataSaved) {
                ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                    Data successfully saved
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
            ?>

            <fieldset class="options-list">
                <legend>اختيار بيانات التحظير :</legend>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <select class="form-control" name="phaseStudent">
                            <option value="">- Select a phase student -</option>
                            <?php
                            if ($phaseStudents) {
                                foreach ($phaseStudents as $phaseStudent) {
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $phaseStudent['num_phase']; ?>">
                                        <?php echo $phaseStudent['phase']; ?>
                                    </option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <select class="form-control" name="class">
                            <option value="">- Select a class -</option>
                            <?php
                            if ($classes) {
                                foreach ($classes as $class) {
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $class['num_class']; ?>">
                                        <?php echo $class['class']; ?>
                                    </option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <select class="form-control" name="prong">
                            <option value="">- Select a prong -</option>
                            <?php
                            if ($prongs) {
                                foreach ($prongs as $prong) {
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $prong['num_prong']; ?>">
                                        <?php echo $prong['prong']; ?>
                                    </option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <select class="form-control" name="item">
                            <option value="">- Select an item -</option>
                            <?php
                            if ($items) {
                                foreach ($items as $item) {
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $item['num_item']; ?>">
                                        <?php echo $item['item']; ?>
                                    </option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <select class="form-control" name="monthe">
                            <option value="">- Select a monthe -</option>
                            <?php
                            if ($monthes) {
                                foreach ($monthes as $monthe) {
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $monthe['num_month']; ?>">
                                        <?php echo $monthe['monthe']; ?>
                                    </option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="thisDay">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

            <div class="container students-list">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Number Stu</th>
                            <th>Name Stu</th>
                            <th>attends</th>
                            <th>absent</th>
                            <th>excusable</th>
                            <th>note</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        if ($students) {
                            foreach ($students as $student) {
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>
                                            <?php echo $student['num__student']; ?>
                                        </span>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="studentId[]" value="<?php echo $student['num__student']; ?>">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <span>
                                            <?php echo $student['name_student']; ?>
                                        </span>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="studentName[<?php echo $student['num__student']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $student['name_student']; ?>">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="attend[<?php echo $student['num__student']; ?>]" id="attends<?php echo $student['num__student']; ?>" value="1">
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="attend[<?php echo $student['num__student']; ?>]" id="absent<?php echo $student['num__student']; ?>" value="0">
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <label class="form-check-label">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="excusable[<?php echo $student['num__student']; ?>]">
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="attendNote[<?php echo $student['num__student']; ?>]" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php
                            }
                        } else {
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="6">
                                    No students found
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="save" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-primary">
                        Save
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <button type="reset" name="reset" value="reset" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-warning">
                        Reset
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <button type="button" name="close" value="close" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-danger">
                        Close
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**connection_mysqli.php**

```
<?php

// This page contains the code for creating a mysqli connection instance.

/*
 * Enable internal report functions. This enables the exception handling,
 * e.g. mysqli will not throw PHP warnings anymore, but mysqli exceptions
 * (mysqli_sql_exception).
 */
$mysqliDriver = new mysqli_driver();
$mysqliDriver->report_mode = (MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

// Create a db connection.
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'tests', 3306);
```

**connection_pdo.php**

```
<?php

// This page contains the code for creating a PDO connection instance.

$pdo = new PDO(
        'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=tests;charset=utf8'
        , 'root'
        , 'root'
        , [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => TRUE,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        ]
);
```

**Table definitions - read them in detail!**

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `num__student` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `year_study` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_item` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `class` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_day` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `attendee` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `excusable` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `note` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`num__student`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `student_academia` (
  `num__student` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name_student` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`num__student`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: @Anas You are very welcome. I just added some more paragraphs and links in the **"Some suggestions"** part, because I thought that you can find them useful for the future. Bye.